# Toll charges issued in a different country

Tags: automobiles, ireland, tolls

I live in England and my car is registered there, I went to Southern Ireland on holiday in May, I unwittingly used a toll road and have just received a charge (4 months later) for non-payment for using a toll road and a further charge for not paying within 24 hours.

Do I have to pay this charge because I don't live in Ireland and have no intention of ever going back?

Comment: You plan on **never** going back? Must of made a good impression.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you pay the fine or this collection notice.

Given the article in the [Observer](http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2008/aug/31/transport) in the 2008 the Authority will be using a Debt Collecting agency to collect the tolls:

> The AA in Ireland said the Republic's National Roads Authority will
>   use a **Europe-wide debt recovery agency** to seek out drivers from
>   the UK who fail to buy an electronic tag or to pay later via the
>   internet.
>
> Conor Faughnan, AA Ireland's public affairs manager, [said]:
>
> 'If I take my car into central London even though it has an Irish
>   registration number the authorities there can track me down and have
>   used a European debt collection agency to do so.
>
> '... The NRA is copying the London experiment and **will fine UK
>   citizens who think they don't have to pay**. Our advice on coming to
>   Ireland is that if you are going to be using the M50 buy the tag or
>   pay online quickly afterwards.'

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely yes.

You must of driven on the M50 between J6 and J7 around Dublin as I believe this is the only automatic toll in Ireland. The others are all manned. There are clear road signs on the M50 specifying that you have to pay the toll by 20:00 the next day. The toll applies to **ALL VEHICLES** regardless of being registered in Southern Ireland or not and if you have no intention of returning. You can pay online or in numerous stores around the Dublin area.

The system is called [eflow.](https://www.eflow.ie/) Their website will have all the answers to your questions.